# XSD: Different Restriction by Attribute Values

Tags: attributes, xsd, restriction

I'm new in XSD and have the following question, thanks a lot for your help!

Suppose I have the xml:

```
<DataGroup>
  <Data name="name">Jane</Data>
  <Data name="age">50</Data>
  <Data name="state>MA</Data>
  <Data name="zipcode">01000</Data>
</DataGroup>
```

I'd like to put restriction on:
when the attribute name equals to "age", the value of  should be an integer and >20,
when the attribute name equals to "state", the value of  should be two letters.
when the attribute name equals to "zip code", the value of  should be \d{5}.

Can not modify the xml, any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using XSD version 1.1 or XSD 1.0?

Comment: It's OK to use either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **XSD 1.1** you can declare alternative types for each situation. Additionally you can restrict the number of `<Data>` elements to exactly four, and add an assertion to guarantee that each different attribute occurs exactly once:

```
<xs:element name="DataGroup">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Data" maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="4">
                <xs:alternative type="NameData"  test="@name='name'" />
                <xs:alternative type="AgeData"   test="@name='age'" />
                <xs:alternative type="ZipData"   test="@name='zipcode'"/>
                <xs:alternative type="StateData" test="@name='state'"/>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="Data/@name='name' and Data/@name='age' and Data/@name='zipcode' and Data/@name='state'"></xs:assert>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Since `<Data>` is a simple type, you need to declare the attribute as an extension of each type:

```
<xs:complexType name="NameData">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="AgeData">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="AgeType">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ZipData">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="ZipType">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="StateData">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="StateType">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The restrictions you declare in the types which are base for the simple types:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AgeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minExclusive value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="StateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="ZipType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{5}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This will validate your file with the restrictions you require.